# GNU find logical operators with -print

Tags: linux, command-line, find

Consider the following file layout:

```
.
├── dir_a
│   └── file_1
└── file_2
```

Invoking

```
find . \( -name dir_a -prune \) -a -print
```

gives

```
./dir_a
```

but invoking

```
find . \( -name dir_a -prune \) -o -print
```

gives

```
./file_2
```

Why logical OR (-o) does not include results from the logical AND (-a)?

Comment: Because `find` operators are [short-circuited](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [Find's specification](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/find.html) ([GNU Find manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/findutils/manual/html_node/find_html/Combining-Primaries-With-Operators.html#Combining-Primaries-With-Operators) has a similar wording):

> **expression -o expression**
> Alternation of primaries; the OR operator.
> **The second expression shall not be evaluated if the first expression is true.**

- `dir_a`

  Since the `-name` matches and `-prune` is always true, `\( -name dir_a -prune \)` is true,
  thus Find doesn't get to `-print` for `dir_a`.
- `file_1`

  Not considered by Find, because `dir_a` is pruned, so not printed.
- `file_2`

  The `-name` test does not match, thus `\( -name dir_a -prune \)` is false and Find reaches the `-print` primary.

Answer (score 1):

Your expression is effectively:

(Match pruned dir_a but don't do anything with it) OR (print everything else)

If you want anything on the left printed, you'll need to include -print inside the parenthesis.